# Easiest way to compare two revisions of a single file - not a repository - in Mercurial history?

Tags: mercurial

I want to compare an individual file - not see all of the changes in one revision of a repository versus another revision.

The way I'm doing it now is

```
hg clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/ C:\me.123 -r 123
```

Then I use a file comparison tool in Windows to compare the current version `C:\me` against `C:\me.123`.

So, okay, this is not an efficient way to do file comparisons for a single file since I have to pull the entire repository from bitbucket every time.

At the moment I just want to compare `README.txt` in `C:\me` against `README.txt` from revision 123.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If the file you have locally is your working copy then you can just use the `hg diff` command and specifiy a revision

```
hg diff -r 123 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a repository, you have it's whole history. So you don't have to reclone from the source to get a particular revision, you could just clone from your existing copy. But, of course, that's still very inefficient for diffing a single file.

```
hg diff -r 123 README.txt
```

That command will do what you want when you're in `C:\me`.